# How can I inherit all the unique_ptr<T[]> constructors?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to inherit unique_ptr<T[]> just to add a constructor which allocates the array using malloc and sets a const size field.

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using std::function;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::byte;


template<class _Tp, class _Dp = function<void(_Tp*)>>
class unique_array_ptr : public unique_ptr<_Tp[], _Dp> {
public:
    using unique_ptr<_Tp[], _Dp>::unique_ptr;
    unique_array_ptr(const size_t size) : unique_ptr<_Tp[], _Dp>((_Tp*) malloc(size), free), size(size) {}
    const size_t size;
};

void move() {
    unique_ptr<byte> hello(new byte[5]);
    unique_array_ptr<byte> test = std::move(hello);
}
```

The test assignment triggers this error:

```
<source>: In function 'void move()':
<source>:18:44: error: conversion from 'std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<std::byte>&>::type' {aka 'std::unique_ptr<std::byte>'} to non-scalar type 'unique_array_ptr<std::byte>' requested
   18 |     unique_array_ptr<byte> test = std::move(hello);
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Also before anyone says just use std::vector, I'm working with a C library so I need to be able to pass in buffers that it can free later.

I tried to inherit the constructors with `using unique_ptr<_Tp[], _Dp>::unique_ptr;` but something isn't working.

**Update:**

I changed it to this but I still get no viable conversion.

```
unique_ptr<byte[], function<void(byte*)>> hello(new byte[5]);
unique_array_ptr<byte> test = std::move(hello);
```

Comment: Why do you need to inherit from `std::unique_ptr`? What is the original and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Can't it be solved through e.g. composition? Also remember that `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have a `virtual` [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/~unique_ptr) which could lead to problems.

Comment: Why do you want it to work? The source object allocated memory with `new`, taking ownership of it to later free with `free` would actually be undesirable, no?

Comment: `malloc` is wrong for most `_Tp`. Who will construct the elements?

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't use `std::function` to avoid overhead. Write your own deleter class.

Comment: "I need to be able to pass in buffers that it can free later." maybe I dont get it but thats something you can do with a vector

Comment: suppose you would inherit the constructors and call them then all but your constructor will leave `size` uninitialized, they cannot work

Comment: I just want a smart pointer wrapping an array like there already is, but with a size field.

Comment: looks like a [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need a smart pointer with a size field you should ask a new question about that.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If I passed a vectors underlying buffer into the C library first of all I would need to ensure the vector is kept alive which I don't want to do, and secondly the library eventually calls free which would be undefined behavior.

Comment: oh sorry misread, I thought its you who calls `free` later. Though it sounds weird that the library requires you to call `malloc` and it later calls `free`

Comment: `I just want a smart pointer wrapping an array like there already is, but with a size field.` Impossible without introducing Undefined Behavior. [Here some "crazy person" complains about it](https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=920). If you place size information with a pointer then you just get more or less a `std::vector`.

Comment: What you need is perhaps [make_unique_for_overwrite<byte[\]>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) that allocates an uninitialized buffer.

Comment: You say that you are "working with a C library so I need to be able to pass in buffers that **it** can free later" (emphasis mine)? Is it the *library* that will free the data? Then smart pointers perhaps isn't such a good idea. Perhaps you should write your own thin wrapper-class around the API of the library you use?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So I have a class which stores the data (was using a std::vector). I sometimes want to be able to pass this buffer, without needlessly copying it, into a C library which will then handle the memory by freeing it later (not possible with std::vector). Using a unique_ptr<byte[]> I can simply call release() and pass the buffer to the C library with no issue other than having to separately keep track of the size of the buffer which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

> `unique_ptr<byte> hello(new byte[5]);`

This isn't a `unique_ptr<byte[], function<void(_Tp*)>>`, but a `unique_ptr<byte, default_delete<byte>>`, so no reason why it would be interoperable with your class.

Comment: it doesnt work with `unique_ptr<byte[]> hello(new byte[5]);` too

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've edited to point out another discrepancy.

Comment: ok, now out of curiosity, I dont understand why this fails still https://godbolt.org/z/EeWWfzv6d

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The compiler messages are not very helpful, but I presume the inherited constructors are all not viable *because they don't initialize the const size field*.

Comment: The constructors I care about are `= default` so wouldn't that work fine?

Comment: No. They're still constructors of the base class and don't change just because you inherit them. I think, at least; I'm not that experienced with either const members (more hassle than they're worth) or inheriting constructors.